# TokBox/Vonage allowing audio capture support when screensharing

Tags: webrtc, tokbox, vonage

Screen Capture API, specifically `getDisplayMedia()`, currently supports screensharing and sharing the audio playing in your device (e.g: youtube) at the same time. [Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getDisplayMedia). Is this currently supported using TokBox/Vonage Video API? Has someone been able to achieve this?

I guess there could be some workaround using getDisplayMedia and passing the audio source when publishing, e.g: `OT.initPublisher({ audioSource: newDisplayMediaAudioTrack })`, but doesn't seem like a clean solution.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Manik here from the Vonage Client SDK team.

Although this feature does not exist in the Video Client SDK just yet, you can accomplish the sharing of audio with screen by creating a publisher like so:

```
let publisher;
try {
  const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia({video: true, audio: true });
  const audioTrack = stream.getAudioTracks()[0];
  const videoTrack = stream.getVideoTracks()[0];
  publisher = OT.initPublisher({audioSource: audioTrack, videoSource: videoTrack});
} catch (e) {
 // handle error
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you share a tab, but the tab doesn't play audio (static pdf or ppt) then the screen flickers. To avoid this, specify frameRate constraint for the video stream. see - https://gist.github.com/rktalusani/ca854ca8621c20488bea6e62ad04e341